# How to ADD data to a BigQuery table using Apps Scripts

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apps

I think the problem is simple, but I'm missing something. Here is my code:

```
  const schema = {
    fields: [
      { name: 'sku', type: 'STRING' },
      { name: 'date', type: 'STRING' },
      { name: 'day', type: 'STRING' },
      { name: 'brand', type: 'STRING' },
    ]
  };

  const table = {
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    },
    schema: schema
  };


  try {
    table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
    console.log('Table created: %s', table.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('unable to create table');
  }
  const data = new_blob_answer_CSV();

  console.log(data.getDataAsString());

  const job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
      
        source_format: 'CSV',
        schema: schema
      }
    }
  };
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

This code **OVERWRITES **the data to the table, but i need to **ADD** it to the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRITE_DISPOSITION_UNSPECIFIED - Unknown.

WRITE_EMPTY This - job should only be writing to empty tables.

WRITE_TRUNCATE -    This job will truncate the existing table data.

**WRITE_APPEND -    This job will append to the table.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).